# Cannot create property 'href' on string 'tile_heading-link. DnkVU'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, fetch, href

[Type: Cannot create property 'href' on string heading-link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnKGk.png)

Comment: Can you show us your code, and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: const Tile = ({ author, date, heading, image, link, summary }) => {
const authorClass = (styles["tile__heading-link"].href = { link });
  return (
    <div className={containerClass}>
        <div className={imageContainerClass}>
          <picture>
            <img
              src={image.url}
              className={imageClass}
              alt={image.description}
            />
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div className={headingContainerClass}>
          <p className={dateClass}>{date}</p>
        </div>
  );
};

Comment: It's saying that styles['tile__heading-link'] is a string, and as such does not have/cannot have a href property.

Comment: I try remove from const authorClass = (styles["tile__heading-link"].href = { link });
 from ".href={ link });"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.